# how to solve this error Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: swift, cocoa, apple-m1

[image]I hade changed my Mac to MacBook m1 and my Xcode V is 12.4 my project run normally on simulator but doesn't on the real device I tried to delete the pods it doesn't work for me

```
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

Thank you

Comment: There isn't more info? What's the full error output?

Comment: i added screenshot

Comment: @HamadaRaouf ran into the exact same thing last week, also on M1. Only thing that worked was opening terminal in Rosetta 2, then doing Pod Install.

Comment: I already open in in Rosetta but doesn't work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63391793/xcode-12-build-target-in-wrong-order-for-simulator/64150387#64150387 ? But you should see now that's more to "ARCHS[@]: unbound variable"

Comment: @HamadaRaouf make sure to also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63955114/14351818)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add "**arm64**" in "**Excluded Architectures"** in build settings of both project and pods project, to run the app in simulator. Remove it while making build on device or archiving the app.

Comment: well done Bro it works with me as you explain

Comment: "Remove it while making build on device or archiving the app." I haven't done this, and my app runs fine on my phone and on the App Store.