# Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code, build app

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I m try in to build an Ios app made with Flutter and Dart ( I did not program it)
But i have this error **Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code**

I don t really understand why, because in the details as seen here, i only have some **warnings** but no errors.

As i didn t programm it , i don t really know how to handle this, any idea please?

i m using
xcode 12.4
Flutter 2.0.6
Dart 2.12.3

The answers i found related to similar topics didn´t really help me

here the detailled output

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 8 in debug mode...
Running Xcode build...                                                  
Xcode build done.                                           684.0s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    /Users/vanessa/Documents/Flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_picker-0.6.7+7/ios/Classes/FLTImagePickerPlugin.m:149:20: warning: 'UIAlertView' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0 -
    UIAlertView is deprecated. Use UIAlertController with a preferredStyle of UIAlertControllerStyleAlert instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                       ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/vanessa/Documents/VSProjects/Teichmann-master/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/image_picker/image_picker-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAlertView.h:27:12: note:
    'UIAlertView' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    @interface UIAlertView : UIView
               ^
    1 warning generated.
    In file included from /Users/vanessa/Documents/Flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.m:26:
    /Users/vanessa/Documents/Flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:328:19: warning: empty paragraph passed to '@param' command [-Wdocumentation]
     @param sharedStyle
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
    /Users/vanessa/Documents/Flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:343:25: warning: empty paragraph passed to '@param' command [-Wdocumentation]
     @param allowTapToDismiss
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
    /Users/vanessa/Documents/Flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:343:9: warning: parameter 'allowTapToDismiss' not found in the function declaration
    [-Wdocumentation]
     @param allowTapToDismiss
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /Users/vanessa/Documents/Flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:343:9: note: did you mean 'tapToDismissEnabled'?
     @param allowTapToDismiss
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            tapToDismissEnabled
    /Users/vanessa/Documents/Flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:362:20: warning: empty paragraph passed to '@param' command [-Wdocumentation]
     @param queueEnabled
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
    4 warnings generated.
    In file included from /Users/vanessa/Documents/Flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/FluttertoastPlugin.m:2:
    /Users/vanessa/Documents/Flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:328:19: warning: empty paragraph passed to '@param' command [-Wdocumentation]
     @param sharedStyle
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
    /Users/vanessa/Documents/Flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:343:25: warning: empty paragraph passed to '@param' command [-Wdocumentation]
     @param allowTapToDismiss
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
    /Users/vanessa/Documents/Flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:343:9: warning: parameter 'allowTapToDismiss' not found in the function declaration
    [-Wdocumentation]
     @param allowTapToDismiss
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /Users/vanessa/Documents/Flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:343:9: note: did you mean 'tapToDismissEnabled'?
     @param allowTapToDismiss
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            tapToDismissEnabled
    /Users/vanessa/Documents/Flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:362:20: warning: empty paragraph passed to '@param' command [-Wdocumentation]
     @param queueEnabled
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
    /Users/vanessa/Documents/Flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/FluttertoastPlugin.m:19:23: warning: unused variable 'viewController' [-Wunused-variable]
        UIViewController *viewController =
                          ^
    /Users/vanessa/Documents/Flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/FluttertoastPlugin.m:70:21: warning: unused variable 'topPadding' [-Wunused-variable]
                CGFloat topPadding = window.safeAreaInsets.top;
                        ^
    /Users/vanessa/Documents/Flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/FluttertoastPlugin.m:71:21: warning: unused variable 'bottomPadding' [-Wunused-variable]
                CGFloat bottomPadding = window.safeAreaInsets.bottom;
                        ^
    /Users/vanessa/Documents/Flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/FluttertoastPlugin.m:48:19: warning: unused variable 'size' [-Wunused-variable]
            NSNumber *size = call.arguments[@"size"];
                      ^
    8 warnings generated.
    /Users/vanessa/Documents/Flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/barcode_scan_fix-1.0.2/ios/Classes/ScannerOverlay.m:25:12: warning: unused variable 'scanLineColor' [-Wunused-variable]
      UIColor *scanLineColor = UIColor.redColor;
               ^
    1 warning generated.
    1 warning generated.
    ../../Flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.18.1/lib/src/picture_provider.dart:50:59: Error: No named parameter with the name 'nullOk'.
            context != null ? Localizations.localeOf(context, nullOk: true) : null,
                                                              ^^^^^^
    ../../Flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/localizations.dart:413:17: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
      static Locale localeOf(BuildContext context) {
                    ^^^^^^^^
    ../../Flutter/.pub-cache/git/flutter-cupertino-date-picker-ee093f3440abc1f951c9936b0f6e09906a8ec25f/lib/src/date_picker.dart:103:34: Error: No named parameter with the name 'shadowThemeOnly'.
            theme: Theme.of(context, shadowThemeOnly: true),
                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ../../Flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/theme.dart:107:20: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
      static ThemeData of(BuildContext context) {
                       ^^

    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 8.
```

Comment: Check this link for answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67060520/how-to-solve-this-error-command-phasescriptexecution-failed-with-a-nonzero-exit/67061401#67061401

Comment: Hello @ShivaniBajaj did not work for me :(, I don t think it is about the architecture