# Failed to run test cases : cannot test target on simulator

Tags: swift, testcase, xctestcase, xcode13.2

Cannot test target “FrameworkToolKitTests” on “iPhone 13 Pro Max”

architectures: x86_64

Domain: XCTHTestRunSpecificationErrorDomain
Code: 2

Using Xcode13.2.1 / testing framework code ,but testing not started

**Note: set (Enable testability : true )**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you provide more info on the error? What does Details show? What does the Xcode build log show?

Comment: very strange no logs, added log screen

Comment: Did you look here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63391793/xcode-12-build-target-in-wrong-order-for-simulator

Comment: yes I check for pod version looks same as expected ...in your case you can see logs for pod version but mine did not get any log